# docker-searXNG: I cannot start a tor searXNG instance (Debian)

Tags: docker, tor, searxng

I am kinda new to docker and as for my first project I wanted to try and start a searXNG instance on tor. There have been many people who have accomplished that, yet I cannot figure out whats wrong.

I've installed tor, searxng-docker and docker-compose on my raspberry pi (it is running raspberry pi os lite), got the .onion hostname and put it in .env and then, I got the instance running. But when I checked the link, it gave me a 404.

Can anyone help? I would really appreciate that.
The output of `sudo docker ps`:

[image]

The .env file (I've hide my email:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want your server to be only available on Tor as a hidden service?

This is not supported out of the box.

Here some information that should help:

- Add `http://` in front of your server name in `.env`: `SEARXNG_HOSTNAME=http://gpfo...onion`
- In Caddyfile, add `bind 127.0.0.1` just before line 10 (`tls {$SEARXNG_TLS}`).
- In `torrc`, but sure to have `HiddenServicePort 80 127.0.0.1:80` in addition to `HiddenServiceDir`.